# Bluetooth Headset to PC uses low quality profile

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

For some reason my Bluetooth headset started using the low quality profile (2-way) instead of the high quality when connecting to my computer. The device normally allows me to connect to my phone and my computer and used to work seamlessly (still does for Ubuntu). Recently, however, Windows 7 decided to use the low quality profile and produces terrible quality.

Is there any way to tell Windows 7 to use the high quality profile instead?

note this USED to work on the same install.

I tried re syncing it several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it started working on it's own again. Windows is truly an enigma.